# Contents Of Combobox appear otherwise in Listview Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

I'm trying to add items to a combobox through a list. The combobox contents are pre determined string but whenever I run it the listview shows numbers instead of the text inside of the combobox

This is my command:

```
ListView.Items.Add(Name.SelectedIndex +" "+ Category.SelectedIndex +" "+ Double.Parse(Price.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndex are the index (ie: if its the 2nd item in the list, it'll be 2)

What you want is SelectedText so:

```
Combobox.Items.Add(Name.SelectedText+" "+ Category.SelectedText+" "+ Double.Parse(Price.Text));
```

I'm assuming that Name and Category are dropdowns.

Comment: That's very strange, could you please give us the code you're using to populate the dropdowns?

Comment: private void BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            productlist.Add(new Products(Name.SelectedIndex.ToString(),
                Category.SelectedIndex.ToString(), Double.Parse(Price.Text)));
            LST.Items.Add(Name.SelectedIndex + " " +
                Category.SelectedText + " " + Double.Parse(Price.Text));
        }

Comment: instead of nothing now when i run the code and select a string  it writes Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboboxItem

Comment: Are you using SelectedText or SelectedItem ?

Comment: SelectedItem And With It SelectedText Doesnt Run